HP 6400 Envy All in One Printer Setup and Printing Issue
I recently changed internet providers and after trying everything on the HP site for troubleshooting I am unable to find my printer/or the printer can't find the network. Additionally,previous to changing internet providers, the printer would not recognize the print type in a document I created in LibreOffice. Has anyone else encountered this problem? Thank you!

Factory reset and then reconnecting worked for me!
